# Creating google map with multiple markers using jquery .each()

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have read all the posts about creating a google map with multiple markers and I cant seem to get it working correctly. I have a results page that lists out the addresses based on what the user selection on a search form. I am grabbing those addresses with a .each loop and adding them to an array. I am then using another .each loop to geocode the addresses and create markers on the map. Here is what I have tried:

```
$(function() {
    var address = [];
    var price = [];
    var image = [];
    $('ul.property-list li').each(function(n) {
        var street = $('ul.property-list li .property-text .street').text();
        var city = $('ul.property-list li .property-text .city').text();
        price[n] = $('ul.property-list li .price').text();
        image[n] = $('ul.property-list li .property-image IMG').attr('src');
        address[n] = street+','+city;
    });

    // Google Maps API
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        $.each(address, function(n) {
            if (n<10) {
                geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[n]}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map:map,
                            position: results[n].geometry.location
                        });
                        var infocontent = '<div style="width:250px;overflow:hidden;"><img style="float:left;width:100px;margin-right:8px;" src="'+image[n]+'" /><div><div style="font-weight:700;font-size:20px;padding-bottom:5px;">$'+price[n].toLocaleString()+'</div>'+address[n]+'</div></div>';
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
                            content: infocontent
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });
                    }
                    if (n == 0) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom:14,
        }

    }
    initialize();       
});
```

I am not receiving any errors in firebug and I have successfully used the code for a single address so I am not sure where my mistake is when attempting to use .each. Any help would be awesome as this has been stumping me for a while now.

**Edit**

Ok so I now have it drawing the map but the issue that I am running into is that when there is more than one address it is only creating a single marker and placing the content from both markers in the same infowindow You can see what I am referring to in the fiddle I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/a7n465az/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working in case anyone else is trying to use $.each to add multiple markers to google maps.

```
$(function() {
                    function commaSeparateNumber(val){
                        while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
                            val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
                        }
                        return val;
                    }

                    $('.price').each(function() {
                        var number = $(this).text();
                        $(this).text('$'+commaSeparateNumber(number));
                    });

                    var places = [];
                    $('ul.property-list li').each(function() {
                        var street = $(this).find('.street').text();
                        var city = $(this).find('.city').text();
                        places.push({
                            price: $(this).find('.price').text(),
                            image: $(this).find('.property-image IMG').attr('src'),
                            address: street + ', ' + city
                        });
                    });

                    // Google Maps API
                    var geocoder;
                    var map;
                    var markersArray = [];
                    var bounds;
                    function initialize() {
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        $.each( places, function( n, place ) {
                            if (n >= 10) return false;  // done
                            geocoder.geocode({
                                'address': place.address
                            }, function(results, status) {
                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        map: map,
                                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                                    });
                                    var infocontent = '<div style="width:250px;overflow:hidden;"><img style="float:left;width:100px;margin-right:8px;" src="' + place.image + '" /><div><div style="font-weight:700;font-size:20px;padding-bottom:5px;">' + place.price + '</div>' + place.address + '</div></div>';
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: infocontent
                                    });
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                                    });
                                }

                                bounds.extend(marker.position);
                                markersArray.push(marker);
                                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            });

                        });
                        var mapOptions = {
                            maxZoom:14,
                        }
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
                    }
                    initialize();
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at this section of code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position: results[n].geometry.location
});
```

You are using `n` as an index into the `results` array, but `n` is actually an index into your `price`, `image`, and `address` arrays, which all use the same array index for corresponding elements.

However, `results` is not one of your parallel arrays. It's a completely independent array passed into the `geocoder.geocode()` callback function. Its length is unrelated to the length of your other three arrays, and `n` is the wrong index to use. You probably simply want `0` here instead, as you also use later in the function when setting the map center:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
});
```

Also, I would like to make a very strong recommendation on one programming technique. Instead of creating separate arrays for `price`, `image`, and `address`, you will be *much* better off if you create only a single array for all three of those values. Then make each element of that array an object with those three properties.

For example, let's call that array `places`, and an individual element of the array will be a `place` with `place.price`, `place.image`, and `place.address` properties.

Then the code might look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var places = [];
    $('ul.property-list li').each(function(n) {
        var street = $('ul.property-list li .property-text .street').text();
        var city = $('ul.property-list li .property-text .city').text();
        places.push({
            price: $('ul.property-list li .price').text(),
            image: $('ul.property-list li .property-image IMG').attr('src'),
            address: street + ',' + city
        });
    });

    // Google Maps API
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        $.each( places, function( n, place ) {
            if (n >= 10) return false;  // done
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': place.address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                    var infocontent =
                        '<div style="width:250px;overflow:hidden;">' +
                            '<img style="float:left;width:100px;margin-right:8px;" src="' +
                                place.image + '" />' +
                            '<div><div style="font-weight:700;font-size:20px;padding-bottom:5px;">$' +
                                place.price.toLocaleString() +
                            '</div>' + place.address +
                        '</div></div>';
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: infocontent
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
                if (n == 0) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
            });
        });

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
        }

    }
    initialize();
});
```

This may not seem like a big difference, but trust me (voice of many years' experience) that it will make your code much easier to work with as you maintain and extend it.

(And please forgive any of the code reformatting that isn't to your taste - I changed it a bit to shorten the lines and make the differences more visible.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael. What you are saying about the array makes perfect sense BUT the map still isnt loading. I just get a blank canvas with the brown background color. Same as I got before.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem? That would make it easier to have a look at it.

Comment: There are a couple of tricks to getting the Maps API working in a fiddle - if you like you could start with [one of mine](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/c3zupt25/) and modify it from there with your code.